# Copy certain Files from a File that contains the specific Filenames with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a file which contains different filnames. What filenames are in that file, changes every time i run the playbook.

Though I found only ways to either copy all files in a directory or copy certain files that are defined static.

filenames.txt:

```
file1
file4
```

Directory that contains the files:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
```

My Plan was to create a variable in my vars sheet in which I save the file and then use it in my role.
`copy-files: path/filenames.txt`

Role to copy the files:

```
---
- name: Copy Files 
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{path2}}" 
  with_fileglob:
   - "/pathtofiles/{{copy-files}}"
```

Sadly this doesen't work. Does somebody else know a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understand you right, you want to copy the files, listed in `path/filenames.txt`. You can do it with the following task:

```
- name: Copy Files to /tmp
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ hqlname_sys2 }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'path/filenames.txt').split('\n') }}"
```

The contents of `path/filenames.txt` is read with the [lookup file plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/file.html) into a string and that string is splitted by the split function on the `'\n'` delimiter, so that you get an array with of filenames which is passed to the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain to me, how the code works exactly?

Comment: I am not sure if you understound my question right. path/filenames.txt containes only the filenames. The Files itself are located elsewhere on the same host.

Comment: Elsewhere means elsewhere in the same directory? If so, you can prepend the `src: "{{ item }}"`with a path like `src: "/path/to/{{ item }}"`

Comment: Elsewhere means in another directory. but with src: "path/to{{item}}" it should work I think. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey, i'm having a question about your solution. Atm i am facing the Problem that if there are for example no files in the filenames.txt then your solution will copy all the files in that directory and not 0. Do you know a way to make sure that does not happen?